# django foreignkey - format output value in selectlist

Tags: python, django, django-models, representation, generic-foreign-key

A form generates a list of all available foreign key elements. They are displayed depending on the `__str__` function defined in the model.

I don't know how to search for this, but need to change this without touching the model.

My model connects with the User model. This model shows the username, but i would like to call the _get_full_name function to get a better list.

```
class Trainer(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User)
```

Is it possible to define it inside the definition of the Foreignkey or inside the model which connects (in my example the Trainer model)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
def user_new_unicode(self):
    return self.get_full_name()
User.__unicode__ = user_new_unicode #or User.__str__ = user_new_unicode
```

Of course it should be placed in your class.

Comment: As it works please mark this answer as correct for future reference.